# Regular Expression or other way to get string in right format

Tags: php, regex

Please help me out.. I have following string

```
<p>this is text before first image</p>
<p><a href=""><img class="size-full wp-image-2178636" src="image1.jpg" alt="first" /></a> this is first caption</p>
<p>this is text before second image.</p>
<p><a href=""><img src="image2.jpg" alt="second" class="size-full wp-image-2178838" /></a> this is second caption</p>
<p>there may be many more images</p>
```

and I need above string formatted as following :

```
<p>this is text before first image</p>
<a href="">
<figure>
    <img class="size-full wp-image-2178636" src="image1.jpg" alt="first" />
    <figcaption class="newcaption">
        <h1>this is first caption</h1>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</a>
<p>this is text before second image.</p>
<a href="">
<figure>
    <img class="size-full wp-image-2178636" src="image2.jpg" alt="first" />
    <figcaption class="newcaption">
        <h1>this is second caption</h1>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
</a>
<p>there may be many more images</p>
```

Kindly help me.. how we can do that either by regular expressions or using other way. I am doing it using PHP.

Regards,
Sachin.

Comment: do what exactly - your question is unclear

Comment: Hi RamRaider I have done code indentation now. hope it is clear now.

Comment: Regex is not correct tool for parsing HTML/XML instead you can use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) method

Comment: Took me a while to see what you want, but regex is not suitable for replacing your `img` nodes with `figure`, a regex that could do this will be extremely complex which seems like a waste of time as a HTML parse could do it way faster.

Answer (score 0):

Although SO is not supposed to be a code-writing service here is a quick n' dirty solution that uses the DOMDocument-approach:

```
$html = '...'; // your input data
$input = new DOMDocument();
$input->loadHTML($html);
$ps = $input->getElementsByTagName('p');

$output = new DOMDocument();    
$counter = 0;

foreach ($ps as $p) {
    if ($counter%2 === 0) {
        // text before image
        $p_before_image = $output->createElement("p", $p->nodeValue);
        $output->appendChild($p_before_image);
    }
    elseif ($p->hasChildNodes()) {
        // image output routine
        $as_input = $p->getElementsByTagName("a");
        $a_output = $output->importNode($as_input->item(0));
        $figure = $output->createElement("figure");

        $imgs_input = $p->getElementsByTagName("img");
        $img_output = $output->importNode($imgs_input->item(0)); 
        $figure->appendChild($img_output);

        $figcaption = $output->createElement("figcaption");
        $figcaption->setAttribute("class", "newcaption");
        $h1 = $output->createElement("h1", $p->nodeValue);
        $figcaption->appendChild($h1);
        $figure->appendChild($figcaption);

        $a_output->appendChild($figure);
        $output->appendChild($a_output);
     }
     else {
        // Document malformed
     }
     $counter++;
}

print $output->saveHTML();
```

Note that [`saveHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) will output plain old HTML. Thus, imgs won't be turned into self-closing tags. You may want to look into [`saveXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) if this is important to you.